# Compatibility issue mac/PC on date format

Tags: r, date, csv

Everything works at work on my PC but at home with my mac I meet a problem

I wrote my data on Excel, 
it formats date `dd/jj/yy` even if I write `dd/jj/yyyy` but it keeps in memory the way I wrote it (`dd/jj/yyyy`)
I save the file as a CSV and read it in a `data.frame`

here is the problem :

```
data$ddn

 [1] 29/11/58 25/07/64 25/09/67 03/01/82 15/05/58 29/07/78 22/03/69 23/01/60 15/12/60 16/06/64
[11] 10/12/60 23/08/78 13/04/67 29/11/59 25/09/56 10/10/87 22/06/60 21/06/76 01/11/63 08/07/69
[21] 22/05/52 06/05/69 04/03/64 08/04/75 09/03/54 22/04/69 29/04/71 18/03/79 14/06/71 03/06/60
71 Levels: 01/11/63 01/12/40 02/07/48 03/01/82 03/05/68 03/06/60 04/03/64 05/01/62 ... 31/07/70
> class(data$ddn)

[1] "factor"

data$ddn<-as.Date(data$ddn,format="%d/%m/%Y") (this syntax works perfectly on my PC)

data$ddn

 [1] "0058-11-29" "0064-07-25" "0067-09-25" "0082-01-03" "0058-05-15" "0078-07-29" "0069-03-22"
 [8] "0060-01-23" "0060-12-15" "0064-06-16" "0060-12-10" "0078-08-23" "0067-04-13" "0059-11-29"
[15] "0056-09-25" "0087-10-10" "0060-06-22" "0076-06-21" "0063-11-01" "0069-07-08" "0052-05-22"
[22] "0069-05-06" "0064-03-04" "0075-04-08" "0054-03-09" "0069-04-22" "0071-04-29" "0079-03-18"
[29] "0071-06-14" "0060-06-03"

data$ddn<-as.Date(data$ddn,format="%d/%m/%y")

  data$ddn

 [1] "2058-11-29" "2064-07-25" "2067-09-25" "1982-01-03" "2058-05-15" "1978-07-29" "1969-03-22"
 [8] "2060-01-23" "2060-12-15" "2064-06-16" "2060-12-10" "1978-08-23" "2067-04-13" "2059-11-29"
[15] "2056-09-25" "1987-10-10" "2060-06-22" "1976-06-21" "2063-11-01" "1969-07-08" "2052-05-22"
[22] "1969-05-06" "2064-03-04" "1975-04-08" "2054-03-09" "1969-04-22" "1971-04-29" "1979-03-18"
[29] "1971-06-14" "2060-06-03"
```

R choose to put 19 or 20 before the date and I do not know why

And if I modify the original data (cell format : text or standard instead of date) it `29/11/58` becomes `20056` (again, I am perplexed).

I thought it was a EXCEL problem but the CSV which works with R on my PC doesn't work on mac
How to correct this R compatibility problem between PC and mac?

Thanks.

Comment: not a compatibility issue. read the csv in with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or set up the colClasses correctly. or try `as.Date(as.character(data$ddn),format="%d/%m/%y")`. Also `%Y` is for four year format, you have a two year format

Comment: I know %Y is for four year format but on my PC it works with the same CSV file. I dunno why it's different on mac. I already tried as.Date(as.character(data$ddn),format="%d/%m/%y"), it doesn't work

Comment: data <- read.csv2("Memmoire2.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) Same issue

Comment: `dput` the data frame and add it to the question

Comment: You could also tell excel to show dates with YYYY. Select the cell(s), then "format cells" > "custom" > change "Type" from the current entry, e.g. "dd/jj/yy" to "dd/jj/yyyy" > ok.

Comment: still dunno why the same CSV with the same code doesn't work the same on pc and mac